# How does C51 reentrant functions actually work?

Tags: c, keil, 8051

C51 compiler generates following subroutine for manipulating the simulated stack pointer：

```
                    C?ADDXBP:
        C:0x000F    E509     MOV      A,0x09
        C:0x0011    2582     ADD      A,DPL(0x82)
        C:0x0013    F582     MOV      DPL(0x82),A
        C:0x0015    E508     MOV      A,0x08
        C:0x0017    3583     ADDC     A,DPH(0x83)
        C:0x0019    F583     MOV      DPH(0x83),A
        C:0x001B    B50804   CJNE     A,0x08,C:0022
        C:0x001E    858209   MOV      0x09,DPL(0x82)
        C:0x0021    22       RET      
        C:0x0022    10AF06   JBC      EA(0xA8.7),C:002B
        C:0x0025    858209   MOV      0x09,DPL(0x82)
        C:0x0028    F508     MOV      0x08,A
        C:0x002A    22       RET      
        C:0x002B    858209   MOV      0x09,DPL(0x82)
        C:0x002E    F508     MOV      0x08,A
        C:0x0030    D2AF     SETB     EA(0xA8.7)
        C:0x0032    22       RET
```

I know it means this：

```
        C?ADDXBP: (add DPTR to XBP)
        {
            DPTR = DPTR + XBP    (temporarily store new XBP)                                
            if (only the low byte is changed)
            {
                XBPL = DPL
                return
            }
            else (both bytes changes, the write action has to be done atomically)
            {
                EA = 0
                XBPL= DPL
                XBPH= DPH

                EA = 1, if EA previously was 1.
                return
            }
        }
```

When a call to reentrant function happens, C51 generates a call to C?ADDXBP first to allocate simulated stack space, but we can simply construct a situation that breaks this mechanism.

1. Process P1 calls some reentrant function, it first calls C?ADDXBP, return address of P1-C?ADDXBP is pushed onto hardware stack.
2. assume that P1-C?ADDXBP didn't reach the code where it disables interrupts, and a context switch happens, now Process P2 is running.
3. Process P2 also wants to call some reentrant function and calls C?ADDXBP, return address of P2-C?ADDXBP is pushed onto hardware stack.
4. assume that context switched to P1 again, before P2-C?ADDXBP disables interrupts
5. P1-C?ADDXBP resumes and run all the way to RET, and tries to return to where P2-C?ADDXBP should return to, and that's an error.

Cx51 documentation says "Reentrant functions can be called recursively and can be called simultaneously by two or more processes. Reentrant functions are often required in real-time applications or in situations where interrupt code and non-interrupt code must share a function.", but according to my analysis it doesn't work.

I think there might be something I'm missing, or maybe C51 will do more than that and generate more code to solve the problem I found. It really confused me a lot.

Comment: C51 reentrant functions actually exist?  Why on earth would anyone try..... sorry, I cannot cope with that concept:)

Comment: Your argument is true also for code that uses the standard stack, for example if P2 pushes some values to the stack. So it seems clear that stacks need to be switched if processes switch.